# NoClassDefFoundError for JsoupXpath

Tags: java, jsoup

When I run my program using JsoupPath, there is an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/v4/runtime/CharStream
```

[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt3JB.png)

And I open the file of **JXDocument.java** where the exception come from. I found the some import statements are red:

[red import statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLz2B.png)

How could I resolve this exception?

Comment: Add ANTLR4 library on the classpath.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: thank you , I have already solve this exception by download the jar file